# Proving that $(\operatorname{sech}(x))^a$ is a Schwartz function for every a>0

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, schwartz-space

I wanna show that, for every $a>0$ , the function $h_a$ defined as

\begin{equation}
h_a(x) = \frac{1}{(\cosh(x))^a}
\end{equation}

is a Schwartz function, where $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Remembering that a function $f$ is a  Schwartz function if satisfies, for every $m,q = 0,1,2,\dots $, the propertie that

\begin{equation}
\lim_{\vert x \vert \rightarrow \infty} (1 + \vert x \vert)^m\vert f^{(q)}(x)\vert = 0
\end{equation}

where of course $f^{(q)} = \frac{d^q}{dx^q}f(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$h_a$ is clearly $C^\infty$. For the behavior at infinity, observe that
$$
0<(\operatorname{sech}x)^a<2^a\,e^{-a|x|}.
$$
This gives you the desired estimates for $h_a$. You will have to do some work for the derivatives.

Comment: That $h_a$ is in $C^{\infty}$ is not as trivial to me as to you, you know, how could I prove that every derivative exist and is a continuous function?

Comment: $x^a$ is $C^\infty$ on $(0,\infty)$; $\operatorname{sech}x$ is also $C^\infty$ and $>0$ for all $x$.